# Dedicated User for Weblogic - apache won't run

Tags: apache, weblogic

I have a java application running on Weblogic on a Linux box. The application/weblogic are run as root. I see this as a security risk. I want to create a dedicated user to run the application.

To do this I have:

1. Created a new dedicated DNRS/Weblogic user called 'wluser'.
2. Granted access to my application to only the dedicated user wluser.

The application is hosted on Apache. To run the application, I first start apache, then weblogic.

When I tried to run apache, it complained 'Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to port 446'.

It seems apache needs to be started as root. But if I changed the owner of apache to root, I'll be able to run the application as root. Exactly what I don't want..

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that an application has to be given permission to use a port below 1024.

Check out this question on ServerFault: [Regular User socket permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/84360/regular-user-using-ports-below-1024)